# How to make password for the database so no one can access it?

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, sqlitestudio

I'm using qt c++ and SQliteStudio, I need a way to protect the database with a password so that nobody can access its content directly; editing should only be done through the program itself.

Comment: I'm not sure it is acceptable in your case but you can try hiding your database as a secret compartment in another file, as explained here: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-hide-data-in-a-secret-text-file-compartment/

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, SQLite doesn't provide such security as the SQLite driver requires that to perform any write operations, the user must have read and write access to the directory the database resides in, as well as the database file itself.

If data security is an important consideration for your application, then it might be worth considering using a database engine (such as SQL Server) which has a built-in security model (unlike SQLite).